# css gradient opacity slide image left to right color white

Tags: html, css

I want to use css, to fill a certain color on my image, it will have a blur reduction.
[image]

I tried many ways but colors can not be inserted on the image. Please tell me the parameters so that I can adjust the width or height, or the opacity, change the color.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use pseudoelement `after`to position the color above the image as this:

```css
div, img {width:100%;}
div {position:relative;}
div:after {
  width:100%;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(247,247,49,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 69%);
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://img.andrewprokos.com/TORONTO-PANORAMIC-SKYLINE-DUSK-1200PX.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply multiple background images on a `div`.

Gradient overlay can be created with [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

```css
.image-box {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, gold 30%, transparent 80%),
                    url('https://i.imgur.com/waDgcnc.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%, cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that I do not want to set up as bacground.

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```css
div.parent{width:100%;}
img{width:50%}
div.parent {position:relative;}
div.parent:after {
  width:100%;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(247,247,49,1) 33%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 94%);
  height:100%;
}
span img{visibility:hidden;}
label:before {
  width:100%;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(247,247,49,1) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 94%);
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QsRE4wQf39Y/maxresdefault.jpg" alt=""></span><label><img class="banner" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QsRE4wQf39Y/maxresdefault.jpg" alt=""></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you :) i resoled my issuse