# Making divs opacity change like a linear-gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like a divs opacity to decrease in direction left, top, right or down just like a `linear-gradient` does it in the `background-image`, but just for the whole appearance (not just the background). Is there any way of doing it?

I've tried doing it with this code: 
**html**

```
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="content">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div id="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
#outer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-left:20px;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    z-index: 999;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

As expected it worked really well with colors, but now I'd like to insert an image as background of the body and obviously it won't work like this, how would any of you do this?

**Edit:**
Some of you marked it as a duplicate of [css gradient opacity slide image left to right color white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295942) but It's not the same;
I'm not talking about making the `background-image` get a linear-gradient over it, I'm talking about making a part of the whole div disappear like a gradient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css gradient opacity slide image left to right color white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295942/css-gradient-opacity-slide-image-left-to-right-color-white)

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547064/5146848

Comment: @Ryan no, I don't think so, I saw that one; they try to fill it and I try to empty it

Comment: @SifatHaque I checked this too, They talk about two different backgrounds, but I talk about making the opacity decrease with the width of the div

Comment: Please move your code from the fiddle to your actual question.  Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a mask:

```
.mask {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 30%, black 100%);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 30%, black 100%);
}
```