# Tranparent gradient to shade a div

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'd like to shade a div to show the user he can scroll to see the rest of the content of the div. Apparently, the only solution available is a `linear-gradient` to gradually set the color for example from white with opacity 1 to white with opacity 0.
But that's the problem: my `div` doesn't have any `background-color`. The `div` is in front of a background-image (not attached to the div). I'd like to "mask" the div with a linear shade, so that the div progressively disappears.
Is there a CSS way to do this?

Comment: If possible, could you share a reference of some sort please?

Comment: Could you put up some minimal code so we can try things out. It makes it much easier to help if we can see your HTML structure and any relevant CSS. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with help on how to do this.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849699/is-it-possible-to-fade-out-the-end-of-a-text-line-in-css

Comment: You could use pseudoelement :after. check my answer in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295942/css-gradient-opacity-slide-image-left-to-right-color-white/45296073#45296073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the job of mask:

```css
.box {
  border:2px solid;
  width:200px;
  
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#000,#0000);
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,lightblue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mollis velit non massa maximus egestas. Nam fermentum tortor feugiat dui imperdiet euismod. Cras non massa in magna dignissim tempus. Proin in molestie diam, a lacinia nunc. Sed non venenatis arcu.</div>
```